# How to Add Git repos as subrepos to Mercurial

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial

I'd like to have a mercurial repo with some git subrepos. I don't want to push the actual git repos again onto the mercurial repo, I want only to be able to track different states of them via the mercurial repo. Basically I want only to push only the hgsubstate onto the mercurial repo. What is the cleanest way to achieve such thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read related [subrepo's docs](https://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository#Git_subrepositories)?

In short: you can add Git-subrepos the same way, as any other external subrepos, just prefix URL of repo with `[git]`